# Transferring JSON from YUI client to WCF web server?

Tags: wcf, yui

From YUI Client I want to send data using JSON object to WCF webserver. I am using YUI's  YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', uri, callbacks, postdata) method to send the data to Webserver. But the web server is not responding to the call. I see there is a problem in sending postdata. WCF expects it to be part of URI, but in YUI we are sending it as a seperate parameter. Can some one tell how we can pass a JSON object from YUI to WCF webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET', uri, callbacks, postdata)
```

Comment: In this case how the URI looks like? Whether postdata can be used while using GET method? I tried with POST method, it didn't work.